# Exhaustive path through 2^n bit configurations

Tags: combinatorics, binary

There's a little play by Samuel Beckett called 'Quad' that consists of nothing else than 4 characters walking on and off stage, one at a time. No two actors leave/enter simultaneously, so only one such change happens at any one time. In the course of the play, every possible combination of actors is on stage (16 distinct configurations).

Here is the play in binary, with each actor represented by their own digit (1 means onstage, 0 means offstage):
0000
0001
0011
0010
0110
0111
0101
0100
1100
1101
1111
1110
1010
1011
1001
1000

There is no reason why the 16 values need to appear in this order. For each number there are four others that could be visited, e.g.
1011 -> 0011, 1111, 1001, or 1010

(1) If we always begin with an empty stage, how many different 'paths' can be taken through the 16 configurations?
(2) Is it possible to start such a path and end up at a 'dead end', e.g., a situation where you attain 1011 but all of 0011, 1111, 1001, and 1010 have already been visited?
(3) How can this be generalized for n actors?

I know this is a solved problem, and probably pretty trivial, but I don't know where to begin researching it.

Comment: This is related to the problem of finding [De Brujin Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).  You could solve this in a similar fashion by describing it using a graph with vertices as possible play-states, edges as possible progressions from one state to another, and calculating how many [Hamiltonian Paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) exist for the graph.

Comment: It's also something like a Knight's Tour, except on a board without edges.

Comment: I have since found the following reference:
http://www.cis.uoguelph.ca/~sawada/papers/beckett_endm.pdf
This is classified as a 'hard problem' so I feel better (for not having figured it out) and worse (for having assumed that it is trivial)

Comment: are "cycles" allowed ?

Comment: Cycles are allowed.